# DolphinDB: How to quickly delete the last element of each vector in a tuple?

Tags: dolphindb, drop

Suppose there is a tuple containing two vectors — (til 10, til 20), I want to delete the last element of each vector, that is, 9 and 19. Is there any convenient way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Please try:

```
t = (til 10, til 20)
each(drop{, 1}, t)
```